# Create StaticResource from DataContext?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datacontext, staticresource

All,

Is it possible to create a StaticResource from an object in DataContext (without added code-behind)?  Take for example a DependencyProperty of a UserControl:

```
public static DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(IVMHeaderGeneric), typeof(UIHeader), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
public IVMHeaderGeneric ViewModel
{
    get
    {
        return (IVMHeaderGeneric)this.GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }
}
```

`IVMHeaderGeneric` is an interface that is instantiated as a class by the consumer of this user control.

What I need to do is, somehow (preferably without code-behind), add this to the UserControl's Resources, thus allowing me to perform data-bindings on UIElements that do not inherit DataContext (i.e. the DataGridColumn comes to mind).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could not create an instance the **interface** in the **xaml** resources, because, as you said, the implementation is out of **UserControl** scope.

Instead of creating **StaticResource**, you can use **Binding** to refer to the **UserControl** DataContext property. For example, if you give the name of your root element, `Root`, you can write the following:

```
<DataGridColumn SomeDependencyProperty="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ViewModel.Property}" />
```